# O dinheiro vale mais do que um "obrigado"?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade, comentários

Primeiramente, a intenção aqui e apenas um debate, acho que o ponto pode ser um pouco polêmico etc...

Sei que alguns usuários conseguem alguns freelancer, ou até mesmo uma vaga de emprego devido a participação no site e tudo mais. Eu não vejo problema nisso, e até acho legal a amizade e negócios que surgem vindos do StackOverflow.

A minha dúvida é com relação a oferecer serviços nos comentários da pergunta. Mais uma vez, não estou falando de ninguém em particular. A minha intenção é saber se essa prática é bem vista ou mal vista pela comunidade, ou mesmo se é ética ou faz parte do "escopo" do site, já que acredito que o core do StackOverflow é ser colaborativo e não "cobrativo".

Então, resumidamente, é ético, está dentro da boa convivência, oferecer ajuda de forma remunerada nos comentários de uma pergunta? Já vi isso acontecendo algumas vezes, e eu mesmo já comentei em algumas perguntas que para a resposta que o AP gostaria ele precisaria de um serviço profissional e deveria procurar algum desenvolvedor e tudo mais.

Como devemos lidar com esse tipo de comentário? Ou mesmo, podemos fazer esse tipo de comentário cobrando ou oferecendo serviços pagos? Existe uma posição do StackOverflow sobre esse tipo de comentário/conduta?

Comment: Ao meu ver existem muitos outros meios fora do site que possam ser utilizados para oferecer um serviço, então não vejo porque utilizá-lo para isso. Se a pessoa quer oferecer a outro usuário tudo bem, mas que faça fora do site, até porque será uma relação contratual entre as duas partes e o Stack Overflow/comunidade não tem interesse/responsabilidade nenhuma.

Comment: Procurar alguém no chat para esse fim (divulgar seus serviços ou recrutar um usuário) também não deve ser feito?

Comment: @Costamilam depende do caso. Precisa ter uma contexto, pode ser algo pontual, mas não toda hora. A única promoção possível de forma clara é no perfil da pessoa, mesmo assim pode ter alguma restrição em caso muito exagerado do que fizer, mas aí seria algo bem exagerado mesmo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Não é adequado, isto é *spam* e [deve ser sinalizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) para a moderação tomar providências. Pode usar um motivo personalizado para a moderação.

É aceito alguma promoção quando ajuda na resposta dada, o que é raro ser útil e por isso deve ser bem pontual. Mas promoção nunca é venda de serviço de forma direta. O SO não é um sistema de classificados, não pode ser usado para captação de clientes. Se isto ocorrer de forma natural porque a pessoa deu boas respostas, ok, mas não para a pessoa divulgar serviço.

Nem é questão da comunidade decidir isso, faz parte das regras básicas.

Indicar que ele precisa de serviços profissionais é ok, desde que não diga qual é esse serviço, principalmente o seu, que não mande contatar alguém, olhar o perfil, e coisas do tipo. Se não temos listas de compras para coisas gerais, imagine uma específica de si próprio.

O obrigado também não é adequado :P :D O positivo e aceitação sim.

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion